# absolute links and mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use mod_rewrite and I set everything up to use "**absolute links**" in order to overcome URL resolving issue. Now my links look like (/file.php) instead of (./file.php) and **everything works ok on localhost**.

Unfortunately, when I put the project on my actual server, links are not valid anymore so I want to know where "/" is pointing to and how to resolve this issue.

(I do not want to use html base tag at this point.)

- localhost: http://project.local
- Actual host: http://project.com

And here is what I have in my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9-]*) /home.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try using **rewritebase**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9-]*) /home.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Yup but look at the examples in [the RewriteRule documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule): omit the / before home.